# uitabbarController view not resizing

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a navcontroller then in the next I am loading a tabbarControllor. I am using addsubview to add the tabbarcontrollor. Some part of my tabbar is hidden could any one please tell me whats wrong with this.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you add a Tab Bar Controller inside a Navigation Controller ? People normally use the Tab Bar Controller as their rootControllers.

Comment: I have a login page in which I have a nav controllor then I added tabbar controllor to preset this view. Is nt this the right approach?

Comment: No. This is not the right approach. It's kinda big. Let me put the answer below.

Comment: Ok. So this approach will totally work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a TabBar Controller as your rootViewController, and set this in your APP Delegate.

   ```
   [_window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
   ```
2. When your APP gets loaded, the tab bar controller comes up first, and by default - The First Tab! You should go to the view controller of your first tab, and in the `viewDidLoad` of that file, use a `ModalViewController` to use as a `LoginViewController`.

   ```
   LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

   [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];

   [lvc release];
   ```
3. If you get to this stage, the Login View Controller will pop up right after you launch the app. If login is successful, you can dismiss it

   ```
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   ```
4. If you dismiss it, it will show you the rootController, which is the TabBarController, and this is the approach used by most programmers for login and stuff.

Comment: When I put [_window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
 in app delegate its giving me error rootviewcontrollor undeclared

Comment: I just had to put _window.rootViewController instead of rootViewController

Comment: Hey 1 last question. I put a welcome screen as modelview controller, the next page will be login. I tried adding login as sub view and hiding it later its not working. Should nt we add as subview?

Comment: Hm. Add the welcome view as a modal view controller in the viewDidLoad of the loginviewcontroller. As soon as the welcome screen pops, it will come to login view controller.

Comment: Nope This does nt work. In the 1st tab controllor I put model view controllor for login page and in login page viewdidload I put welceomscreen model view controller and dismissed appropriately. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: It cannot be that hard. Could you do a postie and send me the link so that I can see the code you are using ?

Comment: I posted it as a new question. here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548677/presentmodalviewcontroller-not-responding

Answer (score 1):

```
tabbarCon.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
tabbarCon.view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
```

or

set your parentview controller view like this.