# presentModalViewController not responding

Tags: iphone

I have 3 classes.

First controllor is the first controllor in tabbar. I am using presentModalViewController to present a login screen and a Home screen. I have a presentModalViewController in firstcontrollor which present the login screen and in Loginscreen viewdidload method I have presentModalViewController which present home screen. The home screen presentModalViewController is dismissed in homePage_Btn_Clicked and presentModalViewController is dismissed in login_Btn_Clicked. The problem I have is my home screen is never presented. Any help? I am new in iPhone development.

```
//First Controllor
```

FirstControllor.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Accounts_Login *lvc = [[Accounts_Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Accounts_Login" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];    
    [lvc release];

}

//Login_view class
```

Login_view.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    Home_Screen *lvc1 = [[Home_Screen alloc]initWithNibName:@"Home_Screen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:lvc1 animated:NO];    
    [lvc1 release];

    user_ID_TextField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"User ID"];

}

-(IBAction) login_Btn_Clicked{

    if ([services authenticate:credential_Data]) {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [credential_Data autorelease];
}

//HomePage class
```

HomePage.m

```
    -(IBAction) homePage_Btn_Clicked:(id) sender{

    UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    int count;

    switch (theButton.tag) {

        case 101:
            count++;
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please format this code correctly!

Comment: Bold doesnt work in code blocks so remove the **. Just use //comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Home_Screen *lvc1 = [[Home_Screen alloc]initWithNibName:@"Home_Screen" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:lvc1 animated:NO];    
[lvc1 release];
```

Comment: No. Its not working. Only the home_screen is show but now loginscreen. Its showing only the latest presentModalViewController

Comment: Your Homescreen might be blocking the Loginscreen view. Try adding: [lvc1.view backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: I am dismissing the view when a button is clicked. Then I think the view will be gone is nt it?

Comment: Yes it should. Use debug to see if actually the code to dismiss the view is getting called. Preferably, set a breakpoint in your switch (theButton.tag) line.

Answer (score 2):

Move presentModalView from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear.